# passing structure variable to function

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I'm studying on structures in C programming. But, I'm confused in this code so that I don't understand. From where is the `b` coming in the function ? How can be a structure used like this ? Could you explain me ? *Can we say* `display(struct book b1) ;` *calling the function ?* Thank you for all appreciated answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book
{
    char name[25] ;
    char author[25] ;
    int callno ;
} ;
int main()
{
    struct book b1 = { "Let us C", "YPK", 101 } ;
    display ( b1 ) ;

    return 0;
}

void display ( struct book b )
{
    printf ( "\n%s %s %d", b.name, b.author, b.callno ) ;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any problem with `void display (int i) { ... }`?

Comment: Can you please explain why it can't?

Comment: Can we say `struct book b1 ; ` calling the function ?

Comment: I still don't get what is your confusion.

Comment: `b` is a value-parameter automatic variable in `display()`, copied from `b1` in `main()` when the call is performed. It really is that simple. What about that don't you understand? (and possibly related to your question, the warnings you (better) be getting about `display()` not being declared before use and having an assumed `int` return value, and not matching that implicit declaration when you finally encounter it, can be fixed by either properly prototyping `display` or by moving its definition *above* `main()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you are confused by the similarity of the variable name in main `b1`, and the parameter name in the function `b`. Those names are completely unrelated, and could be called anything you like.

In the `main` function, `b1` is a local variable that is declared as type `struct book`, and then initialized with a compile time constant initializer. The name `b1` is arbitrary and can be any valid identifier.

In the `display` function, `b` is an argument to the function of type `struct book`. When the function is called, the caller must provide a `struct book`, and that struct will be *copied* into `b`. It's important to understand that `b` is a copy of the struct that was passed to the `display` function, which means that any changes that `b` makes to its local copy will not be propagated to the original structure declared in `main`.

Here's an attempt to demonstrate these principles in code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book
{
    char name[25] ;
    char author[25] ;
    int callno ;
};

void display( struct book someArbitraryNameForTheLocalCopyOfTheStructThatThisFunctionUses )
{
    printf ( "%s  ", someArbitraryNameForTheLocalCopyOfTheStructThatThisFunctionUses.name   );
    printf ( "%s  ", someArbitraryNameForTheLocalCopyOfTheStructThatThisFunctionUses.author );
    printf ( "%d\n", someArbitraryNameForTheLocalCopyOfTheStructThatThisFunctionUses.callno );

    // the following line has no effect on the variable in main since
    // all we have here is a local copy of the structure
    someArbitraryNameForTheLocalCopyOfTheStructThatThisFunctionUses.callno = 5555;
}

int main()
{
    struct book someLocalVariable = { "Let us C", "YPK", 101 };

    // the following line will make a copy of the struct for the 'display' function
    display( someLocalVariable );

    // the following line will still print 101, since the 'display' function only changed the copy
    printf ( "%d\n", someLocalVariable.callno );

    struct book anotherBook = { "Destiny", "user3386109", 42 };

    // any variable of type 'struct book' can be passed to the display function
    display( anotherBook );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

b is the name of the parameter for the display function. It is what you have to pass to it. So in the main function when you call display(b1); b in the display function represents the book structure defined by b1 in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

Passing structures works like passing any other type: The function expects a variable of type `struct b` as it's argument, and then it just works with it. What is happening behind the scenes is, that all the data of `b1` in your main function is **copied** into `b` of your display function. So be careful about that: When you change the value of a member of `b` in `display`, it **won't** change the value of `b1` in `main`. If you want that to happen, you have to pass a pointer.